# Refresh primefaces gmap markers in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I need to refresh, add new markers or remove markers on a primefaces gmap.
By a callBackParam I pass the markers to a javascript in xhtml.
However when the map refreshes, the event overlaySelect is never fired.
ManageBean scope is viewScoped

```
public void ajaxPoll() {
    Marker[] newMarkers = new Marker[mapLoadModel.getMarkers().size()];

    for(int i=0;i < newMarkers.length;i++){
        newMarkers[i]=mapLoadModel.getMarkers().get(i);
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("newMarkers",new Gson().toJson(newMarkers));


      logger.info("refresco marcadores");
   }
```

The javascript:

```
 //<![CDATA[
 function handleComplete(xhr, status, args){
 var gmap = PF('gMapWV').getMap();
 for(var i in gmap.markers)
{
  gmap.markers[i].setMap(null); 
} 
gmap.markers.length=0;
var newMarkers = eval('(' + args.newMarkers + ')');
for(var i in newMarkers)
    {
    var newMarker = newMarkers[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: newMarker.id,
        map: gmap,
        position: newMarker.latlng,
        icon:newMarker.icon,
        title:newMarker.title,
        clickable:true
    });
    }
  }
 // ]]>
```

And the map:

```
 <p:poll interval="#{manageLoadExecution.refreshInterval}" listener="#{manageLoadExecution.ajaxPoll}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" process="@this" />
 <p:gmap widgetVar="gMapWV" id="gMapWV" center="#{manageLoadExecution.latitude} , #{manageLoadExecution.longitude}"  zoom="#{manageLoadExecution.zoomLevel}" fitBounds="false" type="terrain"  model="#{manageLoadExecution.mapLoadModel}" disableDefaultUI="false" styleClass="map" >
  <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{manageLoadExecution.onMarkerSelect}"  />
  <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" maxWidth="400"  >
                    <p:outputPanel style="text-align: left; display: block; margin: auto; width:370px" >
```

After refresh the markers are show on screen, but the overlaySelect event is never fired and the infowindow is not open.

I guess that removing all the markers I'm removing some that makes the event not fires.

Please, any help!
Thank you very very much.

Comment: Can you provid the PF version? And did you check in different browsers?

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much Kukeltje. I'm using PF 5.1 and I've checked in Chrome and Firefox, and it doens't work on both. Thanks again

Comment: If you can create an [mcve] ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can can have a check with the uncompressed js sources

Comment: I guess I have to subscribe all the new markers to the existing overlaySelect event, but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: that was my suspicion to... Let me have a quick look in the relevant PF js files [gmap.js](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/gmap/gmap.js)

Comment: PF('gMapWV').configureMarkers(); might do it... or maybe you can even use the PF('gMapWV').addOverlay(...) or PF('gMapWV').addOverlays(....) which automatically adds the eventlisteners

Comment: I'll try to ceate the simpliest [mvce] example. thank you again!

Comment: Thankyou again! I'll try and I'll let know know. Thankyou! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces GMap addMarker (JavaScript) + selectMarker (overlaySelectEvent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129664/primefaces-gmap-addmarker-javascript-selectmarker-overlayselectevent)

Comment: map.addOverlay(marked) in javascript gmap V3 was removed. I realize the PF 5.1 uses google maps v3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it!
I missed to add an id the the new marker in javascript scriptlet.
Finally in javascript code I call _render() method to configure markers and listeners.

Here is the javascript scriptlet:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args){
   var gmap = PF('gMapWV').getMap();
   var newMarkers = eval('(' + args.newMarkers + ')');
   for(var i in gmap.markers)
   {
      var oldMarker = gmap.markers[i];
      var newMarker = newMarkers[i];
      if(newMarker != null){
         oldMarker.setPosition(newMarker.latlng);
         oldMarker.title=newMarker.title;
         oldMarker.setMap(gmap);
         oldMarker.id=newMarker.id;
      }else{
         oldMarker.setMap(null);
      }
   } 
   var oldMarkersLength = gmap.markers.length;
   var newMarkersLength = newMarkers.length;

   for(var i = oldMarkersLength;i < newMarkersLength;i++)
      {
      var newMarker = newMarkers[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: newMarker.latlng,
          title:newMarker.title,
          clickable:true,
          id:newMarker.id
      });
      gmap.markers[i]= marker;
      }
    PF('gMapWV').addOverlays(gmap.markers);
    PF('gMapWV')._render();

 }
// ]]>
</script>
```

If the list decrease the size I set the remain markers to null to reuse then if I need it.

I hope this can help anyone stuck with gmap and primefaces.

Thanks everyone for suggestions

Comment: This seems overly complicated. You're reusing the old `gmap.markers` array, but it seems to be a case of prior optimization. You could just remove all markers from `gmap`, and then add them again. One thing I found out, is that after removing all markers and doing `gmap.markers.length = 0`, and then adding new markers with `new google.maps.Marker({ map: map })`, the array `gmap.markers` is empty. Thus, a _second_ pass to replace the markers again does not actually remove anything. The solution I found is simple but seems like a hack: use `maps.markers.push(marker)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, it work to me (for those don't want refresh the map):

```
        var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            id: json.id,
            map: gmap,
            position: json.latlng,
            icon: json.icon,
            title: json.title,
            draggable: true,
            clickable:true
        });

        gmap.markers[gmap.markers.length] = marker; 
        PF('gmap').addOverlay(marker); 

PF('gmap').configureMarkers();
PF('gmap').addOverlays(gmap.markers);
```